# 2D convolution of slices of 3D matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, convolution

I'm trying to do a bunch of rolling sums over matrices in MATLAB. In order to avoid loops I've used [`repmat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) to layer my 2D matrices into a 3D structure. However, now the fast convolution function [`conv2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html) can no longer be used for the accumulator. However, the N-dimensional convolution function ([`convn`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/convn.html)) is not what I'm looking for either as it literally convolves all 3 dimensions. I want something that will do a 2D convolution on each slice and return a 3D matrix.

Tiling the matrices in 2D instead of layering them in 3D won't work because it will corrupt the convolution edge cases. I could pad with zeros in between but then it starts getting kind of messy.

In other words, without a for-loop, how can I perform the following:

```
A = ones(5,5,5);
B = zeros(size(A));
for i = 1 : size(A, 3)
    B(:,:,i) = conv2(A(:,:,i), ones(2), 'same');
end
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Doesn't `convn` work with a 3D matrix and a 2D filter?

Comment: @beaker That seems to work too!

Comment: @Divakar After all, a 2D kernel is really a 3D kernel with a third dimension of size 1 ;)

Comment: haha I even didn't bother to look into `convn` until now!

Comment: Ah @beaker that's true! I didn't realize that! I'd say that's the best solution. At least it's the cleanest.

Comment: @beaker Think you should post that as solution.

Comment: @Divakar I will... I added it as a comment initially because I took my main computer to the shop yesterday, so I was relying on Octave, but now that it's confirmed...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[convn](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/convn.html) will work with an n-dimensional matrix and a 2-dimensional filter. Simply:

```
A = ones(5,5,5);
B = convn(A, ones(2), 'same');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use some `padding with zeros` and `reshaping` like so -

```
%// Store size parameters
[m,n,r] = size(A)  
[m1,n1] = size(kernel) 

%// Create a zeros padded version of the input array. We need to pad zeros at the end
%// rows and columns to replicate the convolutionoperation around those boundaries
Ap = zeros(m+m1-1,n+n1-1,r);
Ap(1:m,1:n,:) = A;

%// Reshape the padded version into a 3D array and apply conv2 on it and
%// reshape back to the original 3D array size
B_vect = reshape(conv2(reshape(Ap,size(Ap,1),[]),kernel,'same'),size(Ap))

%// Get rid of the padded rows and columns for the final output
B_vect = B_vect(1:m,1:n,:);
```

The basic idea is to reshape the input 3D array into a 2D array and then apply the 2D convolution on it. Extra step is needed with padding so as to have the same behavior as you would see with `conv2` around the boundaries.